# Switcher for thumbnails doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, thumbnails

I need help to fix my Switcher for thumbnails. I don't understand why code doesn't work. Below code html and jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $(".current-photo-product img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();

    $(".choice-photo ul li img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(".current-photo-product img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});

<div class="product-preview">
        <div class="current-photo-product">
            <img src="img/product-photo1.png" alt="photo1">
            <img src="img/product-photo2.png" alt="photo2">
            <img src="img/product-photo3.png" alt="photo3">
            <img src="img/product-photo4.png" alt="photo4">
        </div>
        <div class="choice-photo">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="img/product-photo1.png" alt="photo1"></li>
                <li><img src="img/product-photo2.png" alt="photo2"></li>
                <li><img src="img/product-photo3.png" alt="photo3"></li>
                <li><img src="img/product-photo4.png" alt="photo4"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following will work for you

```
$(function(){
    $(".current-photo-product img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();

    $(".choice-photo ul li img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        $(".current-photo-product img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

You need to do the index on the li above the img tag.

Comment: Thak you I understood you. It's simple but requires attentiveness. But your answer very help me!